# Visual Studio - Cursor jumping around while typing

Tags: visual-studio, ide

I'm using visual studio 2022 version 17.7.3. I was happily writing my C# code when, seemingly out of nowhere, a strange behavior started. The issue started before 17.7.3, so I thought an update might fix it. I'm not sure what version prior to the one I have now was though. I believe it was 17.3.1

Whenever I type something into the IDE, the cursor will after a short delay automatically jump to some function declaration or the class declaration in the currently opened file. Specifically it jumps to the first character of the identifier of that function or class.

The exact definition it jumps to is relatively stable based on the current cursor position, but I can't figure out how it determines where to jump to. The functions have no errors or warnings attached to them, they are not bookmarked, breakpointed or otherwise different from any other function definition.

It also doesn't matter what I type. It always jumps about a second after the text has changed, and also when I overwrite an existing character with that same character.

It is extremely annoying as I can only type a few characters before the cursor jumps, causing me to type in front of the function name instead.

I have tried the following steps to find out what the issue is:

- Disabled all extensions
- Pulled out all USB cables except keyboard and mouse
- Searched the internet
- Searched settings for "goto", "go to", "move" and "jump" and checked for anything relevant
- Reset settings from Tools -> Import/Export Settings -> Reset all settings

Nothing worked.

I do not

- Use a touch pad
- Use a touch screen
- Have hardware capable of using a wireless (bluetooth) mouse or keyboard

I don't know what causes the issue, it has suddenly appeared about 3 or 4 hours ago out of the blue without me doing any updates, extension updates or changing any options.

I have found [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/VisualStudio/comments/15vdwp8/cursor_caret_keeps_jumping_to_other_places_in/) that seems to describe the same issue, but there has not been a solution as of yet. But it does have a nice video of the problem.

What is the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: I have the same problem. It is very annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also experienced this issue but the visual studio support team pointed me to this github issue: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/69292

It is probably caused by the document outline. Since I removed this view the issue didn't occur any more on my system for now.

For now, the fix is planned for visual studio v17.8.0 preview 3.